# Dynamic script tag for cross-domain Ajax not working

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, cross-domain

I'm trying to use the dynamic script tag for cross-domain ajax, since I can't use PHP on the website where it's needed (we're using a CMS, so we can use HTML/Javascript, but no PHP).

The thing is, both scripts work well (javascript and php) on their own, meaning the script tag is well added, and the PHP scripts, when launched on its own, works as needed.

But it looks like the GET request is not processed when the script tag is added (using .appendChild).

Is there a way to make it work?

Here is the code, simplified :

PHP :

```
$email = $_GET['email'];
$source = $_GET['source'];
echo 'callback({"value": "true"});';
// sending the email through php
```

Javascript :

```
function dlPj() {
  // Prompt the user for his email
  var email = prompt('Enter your email', 'your email');
  // If the script tag already exists, delete it
  if (document.getElementById('script-pj') != null) {
    var script_pj = document.getElementById('script-pj');
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].removeChild(script_pj);
  }
  // Create the script tag to call the PHP script
  var s = document.createElement('script');
  s.type = 'txt/javascript';
  s.id = 'script-pj';

  s.src = 'http://www.something.com/bel/pj.php?';
  s.src += 'email=' + email;
  s.src += '&source=' + document.location.href + '?';

  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
}

function callback(value) {
  if (value == null) {
    alert('error');
  }
  else {
    if (value.value == "true") {
      alert('working');
    }
    else {
      alert('not working');
    }
  }
}
```

Help greatly appreciated.

**Edit : problem solved.** The problem was the following : I added an onclick event on an A tag, so that I could get some information about a user before he downloads an attached file. So I left it at return true;, so that he could download the file after filling in the form. Changing the onclick event to "dlPj(); return false;" solves the problem.

Comment: The script type should be "text/javascript". Is that a typo?

Comment: Oh, right, that's a typo. But this doesn't change anything to the problem :-)

Comment: Actually, the browser may refuse to get any script with an unrecognized type. Did you try it with "text/javascript"?

Comment: I did. I also did with no type.

Comment: @Florian I am voting for you. It's the most I can do here for you :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so that this follows correctly stackoverflow's workflow, there is the answer.

The problem was the following : I added an onclick event on an A tag, so that I could get some information about a user before he downloads an attached file. So I left it at return true;, so that he could download the file after filling in the form. Changing the onclick event to "dlPj(); return false;" solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks for replying my question. I am voting for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works in chrome:

```
  var email = prompt('Enter your email', 'email@company.com');
  // If the script tag already exists, delete it
  if (document.getElementById('script-pj') != null) {
    var script_pj = document.getElementById('script-pj');
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].removeChild(script_pj);
  }
  // Create the script tag to call the PHP script
  var s = document.createElement('SCRIPT');
  s.id = 'script-pj';
  s.src = 'http://www.something.com/bel/pj.php?' +
                'email=' + encodeURIComponent(email) + 
                '&source=' + encodeURIComponent(document.location.href);

  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
```

Comment: Alright. I've made the changes you suggested. The thing is, the problem still lies in the fact that no GET request is processed when the script tag is added. Maybe there is a way to debug this? I'm using Firebug, but I don't think I can see if the GET request is processed.

Comment: you're right, but the remaining is correct, I'll change it :|

Comment: @Florian, sorry for the HEAD comment, but if you set src the way I did it, it is called.

Comment: @Florian, it looks it is the `s.type = 'txt/javascript'` that causes the trouble

Comment: @Mic : the code does encode the fields, and still no request seen. Here is the script tag added right before </head> : `<script type="text/javascript" id="script-pj" src="http://www.something.com/bel/pj.php?email=f&amp;source=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.somethingelse.com%2Fhi.html"></script>` . The s.type = 'txt/javascript' has been changed to 'text/javascript'

Comment: did you remove `s.type = 'txt/javascript'` ?

Comment: I first tried changing it to `s.type = 'text/javascript'`, still nothing changed. Removing it didn't change anything either.